# BigQuery Contains Statement

Tags: google-bigquery, tableau-desktop

I am currently loading data into tableau from BigQuery. I've noticed some performance issue and narrowed it down to a calculated field in tableau.

```
IF CONTAINS([page], "/uk") OR CONTAINS([page], "co.uk") 
THEN "UK" 
ELSEIF CONTAINS([page], "/be-nl") THEN "BE NL"
ELSEIF CONTAINS([page], "/be-fr") THEN "BE FR"
ELSEIF CONTAINS([page], "/nl") THEN "NL"
ELSEIF CONTAINS([page], ".fr") THEN "FR"
ELSE "US"
END
```

I'd like to move this query to Bigquery, however, I am not sure how to recreate it. Basically, this calculation creates a new field.

Thank you in advance,
Udi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
case 
  when regexp_contains(page, '/uk|co.uk') then 'UK'
  when regexp_contains(page, '/be-nl') then 'BE NL'
  when regexp_contains(page, '/be-fr') then 'BE FR'
  when regexp_contains(page, '/nl') then 'NL'
  when regexp_contains(page, '.fr') then 'FR'
  else 'US'
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast response!